# asp.net mvc - UI for nested data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I am writing a information system for a neighborhood charitable organization, as the server side wil be Asp.net MVC.

Beyond that there is no special requirement of the client UI design technolgy or Appearance,  it's my choice, including integrating third-party libraries/tools/technolgies.

At income and updating mode,  the user chooses a family, then puts its data: number of family members, income support organization, etc.
Then for each family member, he puts the information containing various personal details and reason for support.
For each reason for support, will be introduced various details including the amount required, tracking and more.

To sum up, The data is nested one inside the other: family => family member => reason to support => different information.
There are a more smaller number of nesting information.

I am looking for recomendations for a simple and fast building UI way.

I should point out that because I am doing the project on a voluntary basis, outside working hours ,I find it difficult to lern a new a technology that requires lengthy study and practice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **accordion** for **main family** details.

On click accordion item, bind family member details.

On click family member bind reason to support in below other div

All above listing should be load on click,should not be load at first time.

Comment: A JQuery accordion?

Comment: JQuery/Bootstrap any